# Setting Academic or Financial Years in Django

Tags: django, django-models

This may seem rather insignificant, but how do you set a financial or academic year, say 2018/19 or 2017/2018 in a Django model and reference the current financial year for querying, in this case 2019/20

Comment: I'd honestly create a new model for `Period` or whatever is a generic enough term, with `name`/`start_date`/`end_date` (and maybe a slug), and foreignkey into that from other models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using a custom queryset

```
class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def current_financial_year(self):
        return self.filter(datefield__gte=current_finyear_start, datefield__lte=current_finyear_end)
```

then make a manager out of it

```
CustomManager = models.Manager.from_queryset(CustomQueryset)

# Then in your model:

class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = CustomManager()

#use it like this:
MyModel.objects.current_financial_year().filter(...)
MyModel.objects.current_financial_year().get(...)
```

check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods

Comment: It mIght be obvious, but you can also define a similar method `.financial_year(yyyy)` that calculates or looks up the start and end dates for your financial year `yyyy` before returning `self.filter(...)`